# GIT with remote development only

Tags: git, version-control, staging

I need to implement a version control system for my team.  While I used to work with SVN, I now recognize that developers have switched to Git.  I read several how-to's, tutorials, and so on, but my concern couldn't be answered in any paper.

My problem is that I can't develop locally. The system we work on only allows remote development and it is two-staged. So we basically have a Development/QA-System and the Production-Server.

How can I use Git within a two-staged landscape (based on linux) with remote development only?

How can my team development work concurrently, do their branches, their tests and claim something as complete and stage it to production (as soon as approved)?

Any suggestions, tips and hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Philipp, can you explain more what issues you see employing git even though you're developing on a remote server (assuming that remote server has git installed and that you can clone from a shared rep?).  The only difference I see between your scenario and a 'standard' scenario is that you need to ssh in somewhere first.

Comment: Are you looking for a recommended workflow?

Comment: Since you are familiar with SVN already, it might help us understand exactly what your issues are if you explain the SVN workflow, and we can translate it to GIT.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your development is remote doesn't matter so long as the systems have git installed (or you can get it installed).

If you can get a central repository setup somewhere, you would simply SSH into the remote host and then clone the repository into your home directory on the remote host.  When you've made your changes you'd push them to the shared repository for you team members to pull down to their home directories.

Even without a central repository, there's numerous options for you and the other users.  You could all create a "public" repo in a subdirectory of your home dir that you give your coworkers rights to read from.  So, after you do your work in your private repo in your home directory, you push it to your public repo in the accessible directory and your coworkers can fetch your updates from there.

Or, you enable the git-daemon and let them pull updates directly from you.

Or, if there's a place on the server which you all can access, just put a shared repository there.

Or, you can have git create patch files and email them around.

In other words, there's no shortage of solutions; you'll just have to find what fits your workflow.

Comment: +1, I suspect the key statement here is "clone the repository into your home directory." My hunch is the author might be thinking everyone would be sharing 1 working copy, so you can only be developing in 1 branch at a time? Where as in SVN you would have all branches checked out simultaneously so everyone could be working from the same root directory, with their individual branches in sub directories. I could be wrong though, but that is how I read the original post...

Answer (score 1):

May be I misunderstand your question but you can clone from the remote repository

```
git clone RemoteRepos
```

to your local machine and work locally. Till the point you decide to give back the results to the public via:

```
git push ...
```